# How to run binary file using vagrant and keep it running in the background?

Tags: linux, deployment, vagrant, binary

I have a binary file which I need to deploy or run on my linux server.
Currently I'm using a vagrant, here is my Vagrantfile :

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  ......

  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./provisioner"
  config.vm.provision "shell", binary: true , path: "./code/service"
end
```

Notice that on the second last line I have `config.vm.provision "shell", binary: true , path: "./code/service"`. This service file is a compiled file from application written in Go.

Above configuration works but it doesn't run the file in the background. when using `vagrant provision` using this `Vagrantfile` will keep running on my terminal.

I know that I can achieve this using `screen`. But suppose that I have **100 server running** that needs to run this file, it will be painfull to repeat it using `screen`.

Any idea how to automate it ? maybe using other tools?

any help would be appreciated.